# Systems freezes + Memory issues

Tags: virtualization, memory, hyper-v, hardware, central-processing-unit

I have a Hyper-V 2012 R2 server and increased its RAM to 32GB from 16GB. (for a small business).

1-2 months after the upgrade the system started to freeze seemingly randomly. Whether it was posting or when it was booted it would just freeze. I have done full hardware testing and nothing was flagged as an bad, especially the RAM.

I changed the RAM back to the 16GB but the issues still persist. I have swapped the mobo out and it still does not work. I have ran without the HDDs and the same thing still happens.

A funny thing happens with the RAM on the first mobo the RAM available amount fluctuates from 32,24 to 16 gb of ram available (it can see the full amount installed but not use it all). On the second mobo (motherboard) the ram mode switches from dual channel to single channel after a quick reset from the failure.

I have Googled around and found that it might be a CPU issue but I would like to get some specific advice before I purchase a new CPU (tight budget).

Comment: What is the CPU model?

Comment: AMD FX-4300 (fd4300wmhkbox) desktop processor

Comment: Ah sorry, haven't touched AMD procs in 10+ years. I know on the Intel procs the memory controller is on die now, and may be the same for AMD, but can't say definitively here

Comment: Since the Anthlon64 the AMD processors have had it onboard. So mine does.

Comment: @Zepher does that help?

Comment: My guess would be memory controller especially after the troubleshooting you have already done

Comment: That's good to know. I thought that myself but I just wanted to make sure. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Nope, i'd try swapping the proc next. If it's not too old you might be able to RMA it with AMD.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might be able to borrow one from another computer temporarily. If not then I will get a new CPU (and if that does not work I will return it). Thanks for your help!

Comment: The motherboard and CPU have been replaced. It has got to be the RAM. I will post back after they have been replaced.